# ReactJS/JSX support in Netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, reactjs

I've just downloaded Netbeans 8.1 for PHP. Based on https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=250288 , it appears that there is no native ReactJS/JSX support.  Is anyone using this for react. Are there any workarounds? I'm been using Netbeans for years and would hate to have to move to a different IDE.

Comment: Have you checked this link? https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/react_js_and_netbeans_ide might be helpful. I know you say you dont want to switch to another IDE, but actually i use Atom for frontend development and is better, so i can leave netbeans for backend (php in my case) development. What do you think?

Comment: Would you give an answer explaining more on how you do this using atom?

Comment: Done, i've added an answer, hope this helps you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, i'm a Netbeans user too, but because of needs like this, i've switched myself from Netbeans to Sublime (first) and now to Atom for Frontend development and honestly, the workflow is great. I use ReactJS, AngularJS and VueJS, and for all of this Atom fits my needs.

Atom uses packages (like plugins) to support all of this, here's what i use for React:

- Atom (https://atom.io/)
- React Package (https://atom.io/packages/react)

The package adds:

- Syntax highlighting
- Snippets
- Automatic indentation and folding
- JSX Reformatting
- HTML to JSX conversion
- Autocomplete

Something important to remember is that sometimes Atom uses the wrong syntax highlight for some reason, so, in JSX files just click in the bottom right corner (next to the encoding) and you can select your filetype there (for ReactJS, should be Javascript(JSX)) and everything should be fine :)

I invite you to try it, its a great experience and for backend development (in my case, PHP) Netbeans is way better, from a lot of benefits that in frontend you might not need (the most to me is think is "Go to declaration", which in frontend i don't have/need).

If you want to know what other packages i use that might help you in frontend development just let me know and i'll update this post :)

Good luck!

Comment: Glad it's helpful to you ^^

Comment: I cant use Atom, bcz my notebook is not powerfull. Netbeans works perfectly, but without jsx. Atom is work too slowly and too much stacking and use my CPU 100% long time. Its hard to work with atom for me :(

Comment: It's weird that Netbeans (which consumes high CPU too) runs fine, but atom doesnt. Atom does runs slowly sometimes but Netbeans too, weird. But how about Sublime? sublime is waaaay faster than atom, give it a try, sublime is a great text editor, i just prefer atom for minimal differences and there's a package for react on Sublime (https://github.com/facebookarchive/sublime-react). Try it, i promise it will be faster :)

Comment: @JavisPerez, yes, I installed yesterday siblime. But I sad bcz I can't focus tree project by keyboard.

Comment: Well, maybe is the time to create your own plugin! i know people who might actually use it! ^^ is just Javascript :D

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/react_js_and_netbeans_ide1

It's still in early development but it should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Support for ReactJS is now included in Netbeans 8.2

source (last post):
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=250778

I personally don't find it satisfactory yet, which brought me to this question....